# What is the SAR(Specific Absorption Rate) value near a Telecom Tower?

Tags: wireless, mobile, telecommunications

We know the SAR values of every smartphone. However we've got so many cellular towers in our neighborhood. How much of risk is there, health-wise, in being exposed to them daily? I mean is there any SAR value that Telecom Operators have to adhere to while installing their antennas?

Comment: I would guess it depends on local/national regulations. So... Where are you?

Comment: I live in India. I just wanted to get a general idea. I'm aware that all smartphone manufacturers have to strictly keep the RF power levels of their smartphones below the permissible SAR value. I don't know about any such value being there in case of cellular towers and that's why I'm curious to know if there's any. Because these towers are right there outside of our homes and they certainly radiate a lot of power as compared to our smartphones.

Comment: I got lots of hits when I googled it. https://www.google.com?q=india+sar+cell+towers